# Change the color of Default grid in kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to change the default color in the Kendo UI grid, could any one help tell me how to do that

Thank you in advance ,

Regards,
Udeshika

Answer (score 1):

Kendo UI has a theme builder available here: http://demos.kendoui.com/themebuilder/web.html which can be used to create custom themes. You'll just set the colors you choose, then download the css from the theme builder.  Your other option would be to edit the css manually.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I only want change the grid color,I would like to do it in css, Could  you help me to do that?

Comment: Sorry, don't know that toolkit really. My suggestions would be to use developer tools of your browser to inspect and modify whatever styles for whatever elements need to be changed, then make those changes to your source css file as well.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to do in that way, but I'm creating this for mobile, so I couldn't use inspect for this